# How to use nftables dnat and redirect without preceding match

Tags: nftables

I have

```
table ip nat {
    chain Redirect_to_local {
            limit rate 3/minute burst 10 packets log prefix "[nft.ip.dnat.8080]: "
            redirect to :8080
    }
    chain PREROUTING {
            type nat hook prerouting priority dstnat; policy accept;
            iifname != { "lo", "ISP*" } fib daddr type != { local, multicast, broadcast } udp dport == 8000 counter jump Redirect_to_local
    }
}
```

and it's incorrect because `transport protocol mapping is only valid after transport protocol match`. But why? It DID match, but not directly there.

If I add `udp dport == 8000` before redirect it will be accepted as correct, despite duplication of rule (which is annoying).

Is there a way to overcome this? Or did I misunderstand this?

Comment: I don't think that's going to work because that redirect chain could be called from anywhere, not just from rules that have a protocol match, so the validator is requiring you to put that check in a second time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ip protocol udp` (from packet's content) or `meta l4proto udp` (from measured packet's properties. Usually this is automatically implied when writing for example `udp dport 8000`) is the way to tell it's UDP without specifying again the port. Without this piece of information that is only single-rule-wide, the NAT statement will accept to alter only layer 3 (here: IPv4) and leave alone the layer 4: it would accept to change the address but not the port. As `redirect` is usually meant to change the port (But not required. A single rule line consisting only of `redirect` is valid), then stating the protocol usually has to be done.

So you can replace:

> ```
> redirect to :8080
> ```

with either:

```
meta l4proto udp redirect to :8080
```

or:

```
ip protocol udp redirect to :8080
```

---

Note: for IPv6, using `meta l4proto udp` is the only correct choice, because `ip6 nexthdr udp` (which would be the equivalent to `ip protocol udp`) would fail in presence of IPv6 options, since the IPv6 fixed header doesn't provide the final transport header protocol, but only the *next* header, which could be an option header and thus differ.